# Store values from the input field in an array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am creating a meeting room booking app.
Here Input field for email entry is shown based on the number of attendees entered.
I am trying to store the input in an array. If I try to push inside onChange function each character is pushed in. I like to store the details in an array and use it later.

BookMeetingRooms.js :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import HoverVideoPlayer from 'react-hover-video-player';
import { Card,Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import '../styles/meetingBook.css';
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import { TimePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Swal from "sweetalert2";

import { AdapterDateFns } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers';

import DateTimePicker from '@mui/lab/DateTimePicker';
import DesktopDatePicker from '@mui/lab/DesktopDatePicker';
import MobileDatePicker from '@mui/lab/MobileDatePicker';
import axios from "axios";


export default function MeetingBooking(){
    const location = useLocation();
    //const[hour, setHour] = useState()
    const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
    const [fromTimevalue, setFromTimeValue] = React.useState(new Date('2014-08-18T21:11:54'));
    const [toTimeValue , setToTimeValue] = React.useState(new Date('2014-08-18T21:11:54'));
    const fromTime = String(fromTimevalue).slice(16,21)
    const toTime = String(toTimeValue).slice(16,21)
    const bkDate = String(date).slice(0,15)
    let details = location.state.details
    const fields = [];
    const[attendees, setAttendees] = useState()
    const [attendeeDetail, setAttendeesDetail] =useState()
    const [attEmail, setAttEmail]= useState([])

    
    //Booking a meeting room
    const bookRoom=async()=>{ //checking if the number of attendees arenot less than 2
        if(attendees < 2){
            await Swal.fire({
                position: 'center',
                icon: 'info',
                title: 'Members cannot be less than 2',
                timer: 10000
            })
        }else{
            console.log("Email",attEmail)
            await Swal.fire({
                title: `You are booking ${details.name} on ${bkDate} from ${fromTime} to ${toTime}`,
                showDenyButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
                denyButtonText: `No`,
              }).then(async(result) => {
                if (result.isConfirmed) {
                  await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/bookingConfirmation/${details.name}/${date}/${fromTime}/${toTime}`)
                  .then((res)=>{
                    console.log(res.status)
                    if(res.status == 200){
                        Swal.fire({
                            position: 'center',
                            icon: 'success',
                            title: 'Meeting rooms booked sucessfully. ',
                        })
                    }
                  })
                } else if (result.isDenied) {
                  console.log("No")
                }
              })
        }
        
    }
    
    for (let i = 3; i <= attendees; i++) {
        if(attendees == 2){
            fields.push()
        }else{
            fields.push("Enter the attendee's emailId"+i);
        }
        
      }
    
    
    const handleFromTimeChange = (newValue) => {
        setFromTimeValue(newValue);
      };

      const handleToTimeChange = (newValue) => {
        setToTimeValue(newValue);
      };

      //Number of attendees
      const attenseesNumber=(count)=>{
        setAttendees(count)
    }

    //gathering attendees input

    const handleAttendeesEmail=(e)=>{
        const fieldName = e.target.name
        setAttendeesDetail(e.target.value)
        setAttEmail((tm)=>[...tm,fieldName])
    }
    
    //console.log("Email",attEmail)
    return( 
        <div>
            <div id="mainContent">
                <HoverVideoPlayer  id="meetingRoom"
                    videoSrc={details.videoUrl}
                    pausedOverlay={
                        <img
                        src={details.imageUrl}
                        alt=""
                        style={{
                            // Make the image expand to cover the video's dimensions
                            width: '100%',
                            height: '100%',
                            objectFit: 'cover',
                        }}
                        />
                    }
                    
                    style={{
                        // Make the image expand to cover the video's dimensions
                        width: '50%',
                        height: '30%',
                    }}/>
                <div id="roomDetails" style={{display:'block'}}>
                    
                    <h1><center>{details.name}</center></h1>
                    <h6><center>{details.description}</center></h6>
                    <div>
                        <p><DatePicker selected={date} onChange={date => setDate(date)} id="dtpicker"/></p> 
                        <div id="timePicker">
                        <p>from: </p>
                        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns} style={{width:'20%', margin:'0%'}}>
                            <TimePicker
                                label="Time"
                                value={fromTimevalue}
                                onChange={handleFromTimeChange}
                                renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
                            />
                        </LocalizationProvider>
                        <p>To: </p>
                        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
                            <TimePicker
                                label="Time"
                                value={toTimeValue}
                                onChange={handleToTimeChange}
                                renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
                            />
                        </LocalizationProvider>
                    </div>
                       <div id="attendeesInfo" >
                            <div style={{display: 'flex',marginLeft:'30%'}}>
                               <center><label>Attendees :</label><input type="number" onChange={(e)=>attenseesNumber(e.target.value)} style={{width:'20%'}}></input></center>
                            </div>
                            <div id="fixFiels" style={{margin:'2%' , display:'block'}}>
                                <div className="inpformating">
                                    <label>EmailId:</label><input type="email" className="formating" onChange={handleAttendeesEmail}></input>
                                </div>
                                <div className="inpformating">
                                    <label>EmailId:</label><input type="email"className="formating" onChange={handleAttendeesEmail}></input>
                                </div>
                                
                            </div>
                            {fields.map(()=>(
                                <div id="infoFields" style={{margin:'2% 5%' , display:'flex'}}>
                                    <label>EmailId:</label><input type="email" className="formating" onChange={handleAttendeesEmail}></input>
                                </div>
                            ))}
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                    <Button onClick={bookRoom} style={{marginTop: '25%'}}>Book Room</Button>
                </div>
               
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution can be to store them in a **object** first and later when you need to *process* them you can get the values as a array.

For this I refactored the code a bit, we create a `numberOfAttendees` state instead of `attendees` to make more explicit what we're talking about. The initial amount of attendees is **2**

We also change the `attEmail` to be `attendeeEmails` with a initial value of a object `{}`

```js
const [numberOfAttendees, setNumberOfAttendees] = useState(2);
const [attendeeEmails, setAttendeeEmails] = useState({});
```

Now we need to update the `handleAttendeesEmail` to work with our new state. We get the previous state from the callback in the setState function and use it to create the new state. We use the index as a key to set our value to.

```js
const handleAttendeesEmail = (e, index) => {
  setAttendeeEmails((prevEmails) => {
    return {
      ...prevEmails,
      [index]: e.target.value,
    };
  });
};
```

We also need to update the `numberOfAttendees` input to work with the new stateand actual be a **integer**. We can do this by using the `parseInt` function. Since we use a `onChange` this will be a controlled input so we need to provide a `value` as well.

```js
<center>
  <label>Attendees :</label>
  <input
    type="number"
    value={numberOfAttendees}
    onChange={(e) => setNumberOfAttendees(parseInt(e.target.value))}
    style={{ width: "20%" }}
  />
</center>
```

Instead of the `fields` value to map over and render the inputs we now can use `numberOfAttendees`. We create a array of length `numberOfAttendees` and map over it using the index as a key for React. This input is also controlled and needs a `value` prop, the we provide by using the `attendeeEmails` object and passing the **index** of the input

```js
{
  Array.from({ length: numberOfAttendees }).map((_, i) => (
    <div
      key={`inpformating-${i}`}
      id="inpformating"
      style={{ margin: "2% 5%", display: "flex" }}
    >
      <label>EmailId:</label>
      <input
        type="email"
        className="formating"
        value={attendeeEmails[i] || ""} // to have a empty string if the value is undefined
        onChange={(e) => handleAttendeesEmail(e, i)}
      />
    </div>
  ));
}
```

You can modify your `bookRoom` function with the new `numberOfAttendees` state. To get the `attendeeEmails` in a array format you can use

```js
Object.values(attendeeEmails);
```

Full code without the date picker code and bookRoom

```js
const [numberOfAttendees, setNumberOfAttendees] = useState(2);
const [attendeeEmails, setAttendeeEmails] = useState({});

const handleAttendeesEmail = (e, index) => {
  setAttendeeEmails((prevEmails) => {
    return {
      ...prevEmails,
      [index]: e.target.value,
    };
  });
};

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(Object.values(attendeeEmails));
}, [attendeeEmails]);

return (
  <div>
    <div id="mainContent">
      <div id="roomDetails" style={{ display: "block" }}>
        <div id="attendeesInfo">
          <div style={{ display: "flex", marginLeft: "30%" }}>
            <center>
              <label>Attendees :</label>
              <input
                type="number"
                value={numberOfAttendees}
                onChange={(e) => setNumberOfAttendees(parseInt(e.target.value))}
                style={{ width: "20%" }}
              />
            </center>
          </div>
          {Array.from({ length: numberOfAttendees }).map((_, i) => (
            <div
              key={`inpformating-${i}`}
              id="inpformating"
              style={{ margin: "2% 5%", display: "flex" }}
            >
              <label>EmailId:</label>
              <input
                type="email"
                className="formating"
                value={attendeeEmails[i] || ""}
                onChange={(e) => handleAttendeesEmail(e, i)}
              ></input>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what I was trying .